# how to route on same component in angular?

Tags: angular

Here i have multiple list of users. that users id is like(1,2,3,4,5....), click on button it shows first user details after that click on second user details button it shows second user details this is the functionality I want.

but when I click on second user details button, the url is changed but still the second user details does not show, it shows the first user details. So how do I route on same page using userid.

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'details/:userid', component : DetailsComponent}
```

details.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button routerLink="details/{{userObj.userid}}">View<button>
```

details.component.ts

```
userObj: User[] = [];

constructor(private userService : UserService,private : ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {  
  const userid= +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid');    
  this.userService.getUsersDetails({'userid' : userid}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.payload != undefined && data.payload != ''){
        this.userObj= data.payload;
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code of your component

Comment: @mika i edit my code

Comment: I think to get the updated `userid` you'll have to subscribe to `route.params` instead of using `route.snapshot`. Take a look at my answer and check to see if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that you're using `snapshot.paramMap`. If you use `snapshot.paramMap`, you won't get the updated state params in most of the cases.

To fix that, just `subscribe` to the `route.params` Observable. You'll get `params` on subscription, which you can use to get the `userid`. Just give this a try:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    userid = params['userid'];
    this.userService.getUsersDetails({
      'userid': userid
    }).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.payload != undefined && data.payload != '') {
        this.userObj = data.payload;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: can u help for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493549/angular-5-how-to-get-parent-component-routing-parameter-in-child-component

Answer (score 0):

I think string interpolation doesn't work when you dont bind to `routerLink`.

try this:

`<button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['details', userObj.userid]">View<button>`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't sharing your code source or what you already tried but try this depends on what you described

*HTML*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let userId in userObj">
  <button mat-raised-button routerLink="[ '/details', userId]">View<button>
</ng-container>
```

you have to loop on `userObj` *array* the problem is you not iterate on the *array* of `userObj` so when you execute this `routerLink="details/{{userObj.userid}}"` it takes the same *user id* on all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, this.userService.getUsersDetails() is not taking any user id as input and hence you are always getting the same data for any user id link.

It should be like this.userService.getUsersDetails(userId)

```
userId: string;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramMap
            .pipe(switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
                const userId = params.get("userId");

                this.userService.getUsersDetails(userId).subscribe((data) => {
                    if (data.payload != undefined && data.payload != '') {
                        this.userObj = data.payload;
                    }
                }, (errorResponse) => {
                });
                return of(params);
            }))
            .subscribe();
    }
```

Comment: i edit my code, using userid i get partiular user details but when id change userid that time userService not called

Comment: I need to know about it a little bit. You are in details and you want to navigate to some other page? if not so, then you should handle it with another method, not on ngInit as it would be initialized on page load alone not on url change (since route didnt happen here)

Comment: i want to route on same page but userid is different

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code and amendment changes according in your component and service.

**Step 1:** Router Link sample

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details/1']">User Detial</a>
```

**Step 2:** Service created with sample data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactsService {

  contacts: Contact[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.contacts.push({ id: 1, name: 'A' });
    this.contacts.push({ id: 2, name: 'B' });
    this.contacts.push({ id: 3, name: 'C' });
    this.contacts.push({ id: 4, name: 'D' });

  }
  getContact(id: number): Observable<Contact> {
    return of(this.contacts.find(x => x.id == id));
  }
}

export class Contact {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

**Step 3:** Created HTML for displaying user id and name.

```
<p>{{contact.id}}: {{contact.name}}</p>
<input type="button" (click)="onNext()" value="Next">
```

**Step 4:** User-detail component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { ContactsService, Contact } from '../contacts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  contact: Contact;
  userId: number;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private contactsService: ContactsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(map(params => params['userid']))
      .subscribe((id) => {
        this.userId = id;
        this.contactsService
          .getContact(id)
          .subscribe(contact => this.contact = contact);
      });
  }

  onNext() {
    let id = parseInt(this.userId.toString()) + 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/details/' + id]);
  }
}
```