# Angular 5 : How to get parent component routing parameter in child component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Here is `add-new-folder.component`, this component is child component of `folder.component` when I route on `add-new-folder.component` from `folder.component` that time I want `folder.component` parameter userid in its child component, I tried below code but i get console `NaN` how to get parent component parameter in child component kindly help me?

add-new-folder.component.ts

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute,private router : Router){}  

ngOnInit() {     
  this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
    const parentRouteId = +params['userid'];
    console.log(parentRouteId);
  });
}
```

folder.component.html

```
<mat-icon [routerLink]="['/addNewFolders/',userid]">folder</mat-icon>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'folder/:userid', component : FolderComponent,
   children: [
     { path: 'addNewFolders/:userid', component : AddNewFolderComponent },
   ]},
];
```

Comment: Place where you call your child component ?

Comment: @RahulSwamynathan I do not understand what you want to say

Comment: You are doing it right, just remove the `+` from `+params['userid']`, I believe your parameter is not numeric.

Comment: @AshishRanjan i remove + but console prints NaN

Comment: See this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvgsdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: I'm asking your navigate method where you call you child component - share the code where you call your child route path either html or ts

Comment: @RahulSwamynathan i edit my code i navigate on html

Comment: does it get routed ? i don't seem the path you are trying to access is right it should be `[routerLink]="['addNewFolders',userid]"` i think

Answer (score 1):

try this approach. first create two common methods in any common file which will be used to get and set your id.

```
let parameterId : string=" ";
export function setParameterId(id) {
  parameterId = id;
}

export function getParameterId() {
  return parameterId;
}
```

before navigate to child component, first call `this.setParameterId(id);` and after navigate to child component get that id by calling `this.getParameterId()`

Answer (score 1):

Add the below attribute your route link to preserve the params.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/base/addNewFolders/',userid]" queryParamsHandling="preserve"></a>
```

You just have to preserve your queryParams so that you get the parameters to the child components too